# Sum then Divide in a Group by Clause in a VIEW

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, group-by

So basically after creating a view with a case statement. I want to add a group by clause in the current view below. how do i do so? the group by statement example and case statements example are below

View with case statement which is working :

```
Create View v_ClassroomOccupancyJulytest
AS
Select 
ro.[RoomCode],
ro.[RoomName],
ro.[DeviceID],
ro.[Temperature],
ro.[LocalTime],
ctt.[DAY],
ctt.[DATETIME],
ctt.[DURATION],

CASE

WHEN (ro.LocalTime BETWEEN ctt.CLASSSTARTDATE AND ctt.CLASSENDDATE)  
    AND ro.Occupancy = 1 THEN 'Booked And Occupied'

WHEN (ro.LocalTime NOT BETWEEN ctt.CLASSSTARTDATE AND ctt.CLASSENDDATE ) or ctt.CLASSSTARTDATE IS NULL and ctt.CLASSENDDATE IS NULL
    AND ro.Occupancy = 1 THEN 'Not Booked but Occupied'

WHEN (ro.LocalTime BETWEEN ctt.CLASSSTARTDATE AND ctt.CLASSENDDATE)
    AND ro.Occupancy = 0 THEN 'Booked but Not Occupied'

ELSE 'Not booked and Not Occupied' 

END AS ClassroomStatus


FROM V_RoomOccupancyJuly ro
left outer JOIN ClassTimeTable ctt
ON ro.RoomCode = ctt.ROOMID and (ro.LocalTime BETWEEN ctt.CLASSSTARTDATE AND ctt.CLASSENDDATE)
```

I want to use group by to group the rows based on the `[roomcode]`, `[datetime]` 30-minute interval and `sum([occupancy])/3`.

I ran my create view with the `group by` clause code below and it returns an error:

> Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of GROUP BY clause

**an example of the group by**

**UPDATE**

**This is how the view is right now :**

```
CREATE VIEW [iot].[v_test]
AS
SELECT
    ro.[RoomCode],
    ro.[RoomName],
    ro.[DeviceID],
    ro.[TpID],
    CAST(avg(ro.[Temperature]) AS decimal(10, 1)) AS [Temperature],
    CASE
        WHEN avg(cast(occupancy as decimal)) between 0.01 and 1.0 
            THEN '1'
        ELSE
            '0'
    END AS Occupancy,
    (DATEADD(HOUR, DATEPART(HOUR, ro.[LocalTime]), DATEADD( MINUTE, 30 * CAST((DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '19000101', ro.[LocalTime]) / 30) % 2 AS INT),
    CAST(CAST(ro.[LocalTime] AS DATE) AS DATETIME)))) AS [Time],
    ctt.[DAY],
    ctt.[CLASSSTARTDATE],
    ctt.[CLASSENDDATE],
    ctt.[SUBJECTCODE],
    ctt.[SEMESTERID],
    ctt.[DURATION],
    cs.ClassroomStatus
FROM
    [iot].[v_RoomOccupancy] ro
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        [iot].[ClassTimeTable]  ctt
            ON ro.RoomCode = ctt.ROOMID
                AND (ro.LocalTime
                BETWEEN ctt.CLASSSTARTDATE AND ctt.CLASSENDDATE
                    )
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN (ro.LocalTime BETWEEN ctt.CLASSSTARTDATE AND ctt.CLASSENDDATE)
                        AND (cast(occupancy as decimal) between 0.1 and 1.0 )
                    THEN 'Booked And Occupied'
                WHEN ((ro.LocalTime NOT BETWEEN ctt.CLASSSTARTDATE AND ctt.CLASSENDDATE) OR ( ctt.CLASSSTARTDATE IS NULL AND ctt.CLASSENDDATE IS NULL))
                        AND (cast(occupancy as decimal) between 0.1 and 1.0 )
                    THEN 'Not Booked but Occupied'
                WHEN (ro.LocalTime BETWEEN ctt.CLASSSTARTDATE AND ctt.CLASSENDDATE)
                        AND cast(occupancy as decimal) <= 0.0
                    THEN 'Booked but Not Occupied'
                WHEN ((ro.LocalTime NOT BETWEEN ctt.CLASSSTARTDATE AND ctt.CLASSENDDATE) OR (ctt.CLASSSTARTDATE IS NULL AND ctt.CLASSENDDATE IS NULL))
                        AND cast(occupancy as decimal) <= 0.0 
                    THEN 'Not Booked and Not Occupied'
                ELSE
                    'Null'
            END AS ClassroomStatus
    )AS cs
GROUP BY
    ro.[RoomCode],
    ro.[RoomName],
    ro.[DeviceID],
    ro.[TpID],

    (DATEADD(HOUR, DATEPART(HOUR, ro.[LocalTime]), DATEADD( MINUTE, 30 * CAST((DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '19000101', ro.[LocalTime]) / 30) % 2 AS INT),
    CAST(CAST(ro.[LocalTime] AS DATE) AS DATETIME)))),
    ctt.[DAY],
    ctt.[CLASSSTARTDATE],
    ctt.[CLASSENDDATE],
    ctt.[SUBJECTCODE],
    ctt.[SEMESTERID],
    ctt.[DURATION],
    cs.ClassroomStatus;
```

the problem right now is since rows are grouped based on columns, those which have 2 rows originally with the occupancy value of '1' and '0' and when combined have an average of 0.5 which sql server sees it as 0.

Here is an example:

Raw data

[image: raw data]

Data after running VIEW:

[image]

What it is supposed to be :

[image]

Comment: Please include the full query.

Comment: sure @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: `SUM(Occupancy)/3` makes no sense at all in the `GROUP BY`.  Your question needs sample data and desired results -- and hopefully a somewhat simplified query to illustrate the issue.

Comment: @GordonLinoff so what if i don't use the sum(occupancy) /3. how should I write the group by statement with the remaining conditions.

Comment: @JamesFrancoHadi The `SUM` more likely belongs in the _select_ clause, rather than the group by.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen what if i want to use the results after the group by. Like after group by has happen i wanna find the avg value of the occupancy for the 3 columns which has been grouped

Comment: You first need to figure out what you want to ask us here.  Your recent edit leaves behind a very different question than what I answered 10 minutes ago.

Comment: What i am trying to ask is how do i implement the group by into the view that i currently have. I also plan to implement a case statement into the existing view. i dont know how to implement it into the existing view which I have. How should i format the syntax

Comment: As @GordonLinoff mentioned, put down some sample source data, the expected output and a couple of lines explaining the logic to get the final output.

Comment: ok sure @GordonLinoff

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen updated with sample data and what i want to achieve

Comment: Add INSERT statements instead of the screenshot of the data

Comment: What value of temperature do you want to keep?

Comment: avg of the 3 values in the 3 row @DmitrijKultasev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments you can try:

```
CREATE VIEW v_ClassroomOccupancyJulytest
AS
    SELECT  ro.[RoomCode] ,
            ro.[RoomName] ,
            ro.[DeviceID] ,
            AVG(ro.[Temperature]) AS [Temperature] ,
            CASE WHEN ( SUM(Occupancy) / 3 ) > 0 THEN '1'
                 ELSE '0'
            END AS [1/2HrOccupancy] ,
            ctt.[DAY] ,
            ctt.[DATETIME] ,
            ctt.[DURATION] ,
            cs.ClassroomStatus
    FROM    V_RoomOccupancyJuly ro
            LEFT OUTER JOIN ClassTimeTable ctt ON ro.RoomCode = ctt.ROOMID
                                                  AND ( ro.LocalTime BETWEEN ctt.CLASSSTARTDATE
                                                              AND
                                                              ctt.CLASSENDDATE )
            CROSS APPLY ( SELECT    CASE WHEN ( ro.LocalTime BETWEEN ctt.CLASSSTARTDATE
                                                             AND
                                                              ctt.CLASSENDDATE )
                                              AND ro.Occupancy = 1
                                         THEN 'Booked And Occupied'
                                         WHEN ( ro.LocalTime NOT BETWEEN ctt.CLASSSTARTDATE
                                                             AND
                                                              ctt.CLASSENDDATE )
                                              OR ctt.CLASSSTARTDATE IS NULL
                                              AND ctt.CLASSENDDATE IS NULL
                                              AND ro.Occupancy = 1
                                         THEN 'Not Booked but Occupied'
                                         WHEN ( ro.LocalTime BETWEEN ctt.CLASSSTARTDATE
                                                             AND
                                                              ctt.CLASSENDDATE )
                                              AND ro.Occupancy = 0
                                         THEN 'Booked but Not Occupied'
                                         ELSE 'Not booked and Not Occupied'
                                    END AS ClassroomStatus
                        ) AS cs
    GROUP BY ro.[RoomCode] ,
            ro.[RoomName] ,
            ro.[DeviceID] ,
            ctt.[DAY] ,
            ctt.[DATETIME] ,
            ctt.[DURATION] ,
            cs.ClassroomStatus;
```

Comment: i want to group by in a create view.  example :
create  v_view
as
select [col],
CASE WHEN (something) then else end as:
 from table
left outer join table .[col] = table2.[col]
group by = over here

Comment: btw, do not use between for the date ranges, use >= startdate and < enddate instead as in such case the closing interval of enddate will not be included. In your case if the 2 records will have rec1.startdate = rec2.enddate then they will be both match predicates

Comment: How about the group by 30 mins interval?

Comment: try now. It is very hard to do the guesses without having the objects and the data. If you would provide DDL definitions for all your objects and INSERT statements for the data you would save our time and get the answer quicker.

Comment: u wanna go into a chat? i dont really know what is ddl definitions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201190/discussion-between-dmitrij-kultasev-and-james-franco-hadi).

Comment: hey there i cant chat any more, but after trying out the last code u gave me, it did change from intervalseq to datetime format . however the hours is gone . an example is 2019-07-12 00:30:00.0000000 . the hours became 00

Comment: Also, can i get an explanation for the cross apply part?

Comment: everything what's inside CROSS APPLY will be executed for each row. So, in that case I used it just to alias the CASE statement into the ClassroomStatus alias that allowed me to use just ClassroomStatus in the main SELECT and GROUP BY clause instead of the whole CASE statement. Otherwise you would need to put the same CASE statement to the GROUP BY clause also

Comment: i am back in the chat dimitrij. talk in there

Comment: hey dmitrij ive asked u something in the chat. do check it out

Comment: if you have a question, please make the new post. You might get better responses. I'll try to help it there. If you do so, do not forget DDL (definitions of the objects) and if you can export or prepare insert statements for the sample data it would be great

Comment: hey, ive found a problem. some of the rows did not get grouped, causing a duplicate of timing as both rows have same timing. i can send u some screenshots if u want

Comment: don't send them to me directly, just update the question

Comment: please provide table definition and some data to be able to re-produce this situation locally

Comment: i have narrowed down the problem and figured out that it is the case statement which created the classroomstatus . the cross apply section